# net MVC4 oauth login Allow me to log in with same email, different providers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0

We allow our users to log in using Gmail and facebook.
I have my personal email with both services johndoe@gmail.com.
So, the first time i use, for example Faebook, log in works fine.
If then, i want to log in using Gmail, there is an error with the login process.
I guess there should be something related to the case, the email already exist, but it's related to the other provider.
I really don't care how the user logs into the platform, i just want to recognize him and let's move forward.
Also, i have another table where i handle persons, and it's related to the user email.
So it's the same person, using different providers.

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
if (loginInfo == null)
{
   return RedirectToAction("Login");
}

// Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
```

The last line is the one that is failing.
Any idea what can i do?